# how to pass object key(with special character or spaces) in lodash template?

Tags: javascript, lodash

We can pass the array like key in template like

```
var compiled = _.template('<%= [hello] %>')({ 'hello': 'how are you'});
console.log(compiled);// how are you
```

OR like object key

```
var compiled = _.template('<%= hello %>')({ 'hello': 'how are you' });

console.log(compiled);//how are you
```

How to pass key name of some special character like?

```
var compiled = _.template("<%= ['hell:-o'] %>")({ 'hell:-o': 'how are you' });
```

and multidimensional array like?

```
var compiled = _.template("<%= [hello][hello] %>")({ 'hello': {'hello': 'how are you'} });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The whole object is available as `obj` inside the template by default, so you can do #3 like this:

```
> _.template("<%= obj['hell:-o'] %>")({ 'hell:-o': 'how are you' });
"how are you"
```

You can even change the name of the this variable as mentioned in the [docs](https://lodash.com/docs#template):

```
_.template("<%= data['hell:-o'] %>", {variable: "data"})({ 'hell:-o': 'how are you' });
"how are you"
```

For #4, you can access it just like you would in JS:

```
> _.template("<%= hello.hello %>")({ 'hello': {'hello': 'how are you'} }); 
"how are you"
```